# Como puedo asignar un valor al resultado de mi sentencia si es nulo?

Tags: mysql, sql

tengo una sentencia que lo que hace es suma el ultimo registro agregado a +1

```
    SELECT num_comprobante + 1 AS nro_boleta 
FROM ventas
JOIN factura
WHERE ventas.serie_comprobante = factura.timbrado
ORDER BY num_comprobante DESC LIMIT 1
```

Como el `factura.timbrado` es dinamico, la suma va a empezar desde NULL y no puedo sumar eso...
como puedo hacer para comprobar que si mi sentencia no trae ningun dato me asigne automaticamente el valor de 1
probe de esta forma y no me funciono

```
    SELECT IFNULL(num_comprobante +1 ,1) AS nro_boleta 
FROM ventas
JOIN factura
WHERE ventas.serie_comprobante = factura.timbrado
ORDER BY num_comprobante DESC LIMIT 1
```

Estoy usando una base de datos Mysql

Estructura de la tabla ventas

```
id
idcliente
idusuario
tipo_comprobante
serie_comprobante
num_comprobante
```

Estructura de la factura

```
id
timbrado
limite_boleta
vigencia_desde
vigencia_hasta
```

En la tabla factura existe un solo registro que serian estos:

```
'1',
'13317014',
'200',
'2019-05-11',
'2020-05-11'
```

Estos registros son dinamicos... cuando se edita el timbrado el conteo del num_comprobante de la tabla ventas debe empezar de nuevo desde 1.
En la tabla ventas los registros se guardarian asi

```
'56',
'4',
'1',
'FACTURA',
'13317011',
'37',
```

---

```
'56',
'4',
'1',
'FACTURA',
'13317012',
'60',
```

Mi sentencia lo que hace es... busca el ultimo registro en donde la serie del comprobante es igual al actual y le suma un +1, el problema es que cuando se cambia el timbrado ya no hay un serie de combrante con que comparar... cuando pase eso lo unico que quiero que haga es que me retorne un '1'.

Comment: Lo probe pero no me trae nada

Comment: Tiene que venir un numero nomas.. por ejemplo si el ultimo registro su `serie_comprobante` es 10 entonces debe re tornarme 11

Comment: EL where esta ahi porque cada vez que el `factura.timbrado` cambia el conteo debe empezar de nuevo..

Comment: el error puede estar en otro lado http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4d2b86/2/0

Comment: si creo que es por el `where`, porque sin el where funciona

Comment: sin datos de ejemplo es difícil saber, el join o el where pueden estar trayendo o intentado traer cosas que nunca cumplen la condición

Comment: ya actualice la pregunta

Comment: como es la relación entre tablas? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/39df56/2/0

Comment: No existe una relación... la serie y el numero de comprobante se guarda como un campo mas de ventas...

Answer (score 1):

Prueba utilizando coalesce, lo que hace es retornarte el primer valor no nulo en la lista de parámetros que le envíes, si el resultado de la suma de *num_comprobante + 1* es null entonces retornara 1

```
coalesce(null, 1)
```

la consulta quedaría así:

```
SELECT coalesce(num_comprobante +1, 1) AS nro_boleta 
FROM ventas
JOIN factura
WHERE ventas.serie_comprobante = factura.timbrado
ORDER BY num_comprobante DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: me pinta en rojo como un error de sintax el `coalesce(null, 1)`, probe agregandole una como y ni aun asi, tambien probe sin esa line y sigue sin estirarme ningun valor

Comment: mira ese ejemplo
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trymysql.asp?filename=trysql_func_mysql_coalesce2

Comment: Estuve mirando pero nada que me funciona...

Comment: probe de esta forma y no me trae nada... `SELECT coalesce(num_comprobante +1, 1) AS nro_boleta 
FROM ventas
JOIN factura
WHERE ventas.serie_comprobante = factura.timbrado
ORDER BY num_comprobante DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: creo que el error que te marca es por el join, lo estas haciendo mal.
no se que campos tienen tus tablas pero te doy un ejemplo de como seria...
FROM ventas v
JOIN factura f ON f.facturaID = v.ventaID;

Comment: probe tambien de la forma en que facilistaste y tampoco.. estoy algo frustrado ya jaja

Comment: jajaja animos, prueba sin el join, despues te documentas y lo agregas

Answer (score 0):

en ves de utilizar IFNULL prueba:

```
ISNULL(tucolumna, 0 )
```

Saludos

Comment: `Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ISNULL'` me sale este mensaje

Comment: isnull para reemplazar es de sql server, ifnull es la versión mysql. isnull de mysql toma un solo parámetro y devuelve 0 o 1 ( si es null )